# 'Replace All' functionality for a file or NSString

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios4

I want to replace a particular substring from a file or a NSString with another string. This is like typical 'Replace All' functionality. Can you please suggest any existing routine or function for this.

Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can not edit a NSString. You need to use NSMutableString.

```
[myMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"target" withString:@"replacement" options:NSLiteralSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, [myMutableString length])];
```

Note : I have not compiled the code.

Answer (score 2):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` will do the job.

```
NSString *newString = [actualString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"find substring" withString:@"replace with this"];
```

Comment: This is not replacing the actual string, rather returning a new string. Though it will be sufficient in many cases.